# Are the angles adjacent?

Tags: geometry, soft-question

> $\angle 1 $ and $\angle 2$ are adjacent .
> So are $\angle AOD$ and $\angle BOD$ also adjacent. ? I am confused.

[image]

**EDIT:**

Suppose the point $C$ is not in the diagram , then in this case are  $\angle AOD$ and $\angle BOD$ adjacent ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition.**  Two coplanar angles are said to be *adjacent* if they share a common vertex and a common side but no common interior points.

While $\angle AOD$ and $\angle BOD$ share a common vertex (point $0$) and a common side ($\overrightarrow{OD}$), they are not adjacent since $C$ is a common interior point of the two angles.

Examples of adjacent angles in the diagram include $\angle AOB$ and $\angle BOC$, $\angle AOB$ and $\angle BOD$, $\angle AOC$ and $\angle COD$, and $\angle BOC$ and $\angle COD$.

**Edit:**  In your new diagram, $\angle AOD$ and $\angle BOD$ are not adjacent since they share interior points.  For instance, if $\overrightarrow{OC}$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BOD$, then point $C$ is in the interior of both $\angle AOD$ and $\angle BOD$.

Comment: Edited the question with doubt.

Comment: @RK  I have edited my answer to address your concern.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not. They share the "space" occupied by angle $\angle AOC$. $2$ angles are adjacent if they share a side, and have a common vertex. Angles $\angle AOB$, and $\angle COB$ are adjacent.

Comment: ok so $\angle AOB,\quad \angle BOC,\quad \angle COD,$ are adjacent . While $\angle AOB$ and $\angle AOD$ ,$\angle AOB$ and $\angle AOC$, are not adjacent